# Android Lint not detect UnusedAttribute

Tags: android, lint

In an empty project(create from new project),Android Studio can not detect lint issue "UnusedAttribute", neither code editor display hint or run Ananlyze manually(the item is checked).

And there is **no lint.xml** or lint config in build.gradle file in project.

[android studio screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xgmd1.png)

my code is

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:paddingHorizontal="52dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

**android:paddingHorizontal** is introduced in version 26, and my minSdkVersion is 16.

Also, command line

```
./gradlew :app:lintDebug
```

output:**lint-results-debug.html** also show no detect "UnusedAttribute" problem.

I think it is my env or ide problem, but do not know what is it.
Anyone have this problem?

Additional information:

I want a clean project to figure out this problem and create empty project. In my production project Android studio also can not detect **android:paddingHorizontal** issue, but can detect **android:networkSecurityConfig**, and command line output is here:

[lint-results-debug.html screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7k5C2.png)

Comment: Did you try Invalidate Caches / Restart in Android Studio?

Comment: @RazvanS.  Just tried, nothing happened.

Comment: add code to module build.gradle
```lintOptions {
    // disable 'PxUsage', 'SpUsage', 'UnusedAttribute'
    enable 'PxUsage', 'SpUsage', 'UnusedAttribute'
}```
**PxUsage** and **SpUsage** can be turned on or off, but **UnusedAttribute(paddingHorizontal attribute)** not be detected.

Comment: It is like that  configuration somewhere override the enable config, but not sure.